# Grails with Geb/Spock : Grails doesn't take my baseUrl

Tags: grails, spock, geb

I'm using Grails 2.2.1 with the recent Geb version. My Spec test files are under
functional/com.geb.mytest/

My GebConfig is on the same package as my Specs..

```
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile

driver = {
    FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile()
    new FirefoxDriver(firefoxProfile)
}

reportsDir = "target/test-reports"
baseUrl =  'http://myserver.com'

waiting {
    timeout = 5
    retryInterval = 0.5

    presets {
        slow {
            timeout = 20
            retryInterval = 1
        }
        quick {
            timeout = 1.5
            retryInterval = 0.3
        }
    }
}

environments {
}
```

When I run `grails test-app  -functional` my baseUrl is not taken in consideration...instead I have a localhost url..

Is there a way to avoid putting the baseUrl as an argument in the grails test-app command?

Any idea?
Thanks in advance

Comment: try browser.config.baseUrl =

Answer (score 1):

Try setting up baseUrl in class which is extended for every test class you have:

```
class BaseUrlTest extends GroovyTestCase {

    def baseURL

    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        baseURL = 'your url here'
    }

}
```

then your test class looks like this

```
class myTests extends BaseUrlTest {
    void testSomething() {}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying.In fact I'm extending GebReportingSpec and it has not a setUp() method. So it didn't work..

Comment: In that case create custom environment and set grailsServerUrl to match your needs. Only then you will have to run tests with your custom test environment.

Comment: GebReportingSpec has setup() instead of setUp(): https://github.com/geb/geb/blob/master/module/geb-spock/src/main/groovy/geb/spock/GebReportingSpec.groovy

Comment: In Spock it's `def setup() { ... }`, and the super method (if any) is called automatically.